# Is it shirk to wish that Allah didn’t exist?

Tags: shirk

Recently I’ve been taking Islam seriously, I’ve been praying and reading Quran, etc. I love Allah and only worship Him but sometimes I get thoughts like “I could do so much and enjoy life if Allah and religion never existed”. I know this is wrong (and also quite hard to understand)  but sometimes I get frustrated about the things I can’t  do because Islam forbids it. I try to convince myself that I don’t actually think this but I honestly can’t tell whether I actually think it or whether it’s shaitaan. I’m terrified about this and I don’t know what to do. Is this Shirk, is it just frustration? Please help me, I feel really depressed because I can’t escape this. Jazakallah

Comment: Shirk means that you believe not Allah only is a deity. My interpretation of your post rather is that the relevant topic might be kufr rather than shirk

Comment: This is a common question with youth these days. I have made an attempt to answer it here https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/56461/4058. The short answer is unlawful pleasures are harmful for our psychological health and/or in the long run for harmony in our life and ultimately for our eternal existence.

Answer (score 1):

As sallamu alaykum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuhu 
May allah have mercy on you.
This situation doesn't need a long response theres many hadith proving whispers itself do not take you out of fold of islam but with the condition you do not agree with these whispers,act upon them etc.

Say i seek refuge in allah and know that thought islam restricts my life is one which crosses many peoples minds who have just begun practising but its because your heart is still inclined to those bad things because allah hasn't prohibited us except. From whats harmful so ask allah to cure whats in your heart by learning knowledge etc and doing more worship.
Lastly, learn if those things you think islam restricts you from are actually harram but do so with sincerity dont find a sheikh who says everything is halal.